# Move font-awesome icon to the right on hover

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
<div class="cta-button">
  <a href="my-link">My link</a>
</div>
```

With the following scss applied

```
.cta-button a {
  background: $yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  @include sans-p3-black;
  @include link_reset;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
    &:after {
      @include fa('\f178');
      margin-left: 10px;
      color: $white;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
    &:hover {
      &:after {
        margin-left: 15px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
      }
    }
}
```

When I increase the margin-left with 5 px (since i want the font awesome icon to move to the right on hover), the text in the a tag gets pushed to the left.

I am using the same scss for a button element, there is works perfectly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: use translate instead to move only the icon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the transform property as opposed to margin?

```
transform: translateX(5px);
```

Really good blog post from CSS tricks if you've not used transforms before: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

```
.cta-button a {
  background: $yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  @include sans-p3-black;
  @include link_reset;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
    &:after {
      @include fa('\f178');
      margin-left: 10px;
      color: $white;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
    &:hover {
      &:after {
        transform: translateX(5px);
      }
    }
}
```

You will need to add in browser prefixes for support.